# How to delete text msg at inbox in android studio from a special number?

Tags: android, android-studio, text, broadcastreceiver, sms

I have searched a lot but every method did not work
what should I do?
can anyone here guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't delete SMS messages from the inbox on devices with Android 4.4 or latest OS / API.

> The system now allows only the default app to write message data
>   to the provider, although other apps can read at any time.

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat.html

No exception will be thrown if you try; nothing will be deleted.

Answer (score -1):

Create your own special id using timestamp and store it in your database using model in android studio i hope that should work.